# Entire array's values being overwritten with each iteration in for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, for-loop, windows-phone-8

I have a for loop that iterates through an object array to set the values for the drawing of the object. Below is the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < screenBottom.Length; i++)
        {
            int newPostion = i * screenBottom[i].sourceRect.Width; 
            //go through sourceRect as we're using drawSimple mode
            screenBottom[i].sourceRect.X = newPostion; 
            screenBottom[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
```

However each time a new value for sourceRect.X is set the value of sourceRect.X for ALL the objects in the array is overwritten. By the end of the for loop the value for all sourceRect.X's is equal to what only the last value should be. Through some testing I found this ONLY happens in a loop. If I change the values outside of a loop such an occurrence does not happen. Please help!

Comment: How is the array initialized?

Comment: Could you show us how do you set screenBottom value?

Comment: @Selman22 he doesn't want to change the last value, he's saying that all the items in the array have the same value as the last item in the array.

Comment: You probably have the same sourceRect instance for every screenBottom. That means that although your accessing different instances of screenBottom they all reference the same rectangle.

Comment: Have you checked if each element in the array happen to point to the same sourceRect object?

Comment: Sorry the array is initialized as such. "screenBottom = new Image[3];" Then in a for loop "screenBottom[i] = imageA;". So you guys were write, all elements were pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the array contains the same object lots of times, i.e. accidentally:

```
SomeType[] screenBottom = new SomeType[n];
for(int i = 0 ; i < screenBottom.Length ; i++)
    screenBottom[i] = theSameInstance;
```

You can check this simply with `ReferenceEquals(screenBottom[0], screenBottom[1])` - if it returns `true`, this is the problem.

Note it could *also* be the case that all the *array items* are different, but that they all talk to the same `sourceRect` instance; you can check that with `ReferenceEquals(screenBottom[0].sourceRect, screenBottom[1].sourceRect)`

Comment: This is the only possibility really based on the given code. +1.

Comment: @DeeMac well, theoretically the array could contain different objects that *each act as pass-thrus* to some single underlying object, but that is just a more complicated way of expressing the same fundamental issue

Comment: Thanks this is right but I want all elements to be the same. How do I get them to have the same values without pointing to the same object? I'd prefer not to set the values for every object manually.

Comment: @Tariq I'm confused: if you are intentionally using the same element, why is it a surprise that changing one changes them all? For example, if I give you 3 pieces of paper, **each with the same address on**, and tell you to go to the house from the first address and paint the door blue: would it surprise you that if you went to the (same) address on the 2nd/3rd pieces of paper, that you found the door was blue (and probably still wet)?

Comment: You're right a fundamental slip in my programming as I don't have a lot of practice. But I was just aiming for all three of these objects to have the same values. How would I achieve this? Also why did this only happen in a for loop whereas when I changed a value outside of the for loop it did not happen?

Comment: @Tariq the point is that if you use the same element each time, you don't **have** 3 objects: you have 1. I cannot comment on the last part without some code that shows *exactly* what you are doing.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help I'll try to figure it out the rest myself.